# Steps to implement PageRank Algorithm on a local set of webpages

Tags: search-algorithms, searching

I just completed a detailed theoretical mathematical study about the PageRank algorithm, I want to make a sample implementation to make some tests and play with it, supposing that I have a local set/folder full of a several webpages, representing a mini Web, I want to make a small software where I can make searches by implementing the PageRank algorithm (with some modifications in the algorithm) and make tests and simulations.

From what I know, I should crawl and index those web pages, then play with my ranking.

Is there a solution that provide me crawling and indexing and spares me the effort of working on them so I can focus on my main problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately, requests for recommendations for software are off-topic for this site.  Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: pagerank runs on a graph. you can create the graph in different ways.

Comment: @vzn Is there any tool/library that can help me make that graph/Matrix out of a set of locally stored webpages ?